# Android offline/online database access

Tags: android, database, local

I am thinking about Android database approach. I suppose my application will have two modes, offline (in places without internet connection) and online, which will have the highest priority. While offline, all DTB queries (load from DTB, save data do DTB) will be done with local SQLite. While online, there will be check, whethere something changed in offline mode, and if so, the same operations would be done online. Next DTB queries will be done online for as long as Android phone remains online.

Here is the thing, I am planning to do some Interface and for each access I will define its own behavior. But before it, I was looking for something from Android API, which could help me not to do that interface. I have found only Content Providers, but it seems to me, that this is useful only for local database. Do you know about another helpfull "thing" from Android API, which could help me in this case?

Thanks

Comment: "...Content Providers, but it seems to me, that this is useful only for local database ..." not true ... take a look at source code of google search provider from AOSP it changing json response to cursor "at fly" edit: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.4_r1/com/android/quicksearchbox/google/GoogleSuggestClient.java and realated

Comment: thanks, but where can I find it?

Comment: wrong link ... this should be ok: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.4_r1/com/android/quicksearchbox/google/GoogleSuggestionProvider.java?av=f  and "BackedCursor" http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.4_r1/com/android/quicksearchbox/SuggestionCursorBackedCursor.java#SuggestionCursorBackedCursor

Comment: Thanks, still I don't see solution here :-(

Comment: or ... if there is not so much data (fx 40MB) - always use offline db but sync it with your server sometimes ...

Comment: about `still I don't see solution` ... build contentprovider which checks if android is ofline/online and on query it returns local db cursor or "live" cursor backed from json respons of your online service (if data should be read only normal web service (prefer JSON over xml responses, if you need to update/delete/insert then build some REST service)